# Zendesk Action Bar Color change (Android)

Tags: android, zendesk

I am trying to change the action bar color in my Zendesk Activity.

Below is my style code for the same.

```
 <style name="ZendeskCustom" parent="ZendeskSdkTheme.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/baseColor</item>     
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/baseColor</item>     
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blueAccent</item>     
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/baseColor</item>
    </style>
```

Help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this  to change  the color of **ActionBar** you need to your **colorPrimary** in `color.XML`

**Sample code**

`<item name="colorPrimary">#FF4081</item>`

Comment: Didnt work. I get a null pointer for getActionBar and xml change didnt work either.

Comment: @VarunJoshi you need to change your **colorPrimary** in Color.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add below XML snippet in style.xml

```
<style name="ZenDeskTheme" parent="ZendeskSdkTheme.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorBlack</item>
</style>
```

Add below activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity  
        android:exported="false"
        android:name="zendesk.messaging.MessagingActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ZenDeskTheme" />
```

you can handle ZENDESK messaging activity colors separately.(android:exported="false") is for android 12 users